# Cuda, first connection with the card (Lost time)

Tags: cuda, communication, tesla

When I start my program and a communication with my card (Tesla K20c), I lost a lot's of time when I do the first call to the card inside my code and i don't know why. it seems every time he tries to search all possible cards. if I use cudasetdevice() to define my card I have the same problem.

user time (s): 1.420

system time (s): 4.660

elapsed time (s): 6.490

The system time represent this lost time. When I run my program on an other computer with a GeForce GTX 560 Ti (a less powerful and older card) you can see the system time is normal.

user time (s): 1.620

system time (s): 0.700

elapsed time (s): 3.120

this problem is double the time of the program and I would understand why. this is the first time I have this kind of problem with a card.

**Is it because the card is too recent and the cuda library is not yet optimized for?**

I use version 5.0 cuda.

Comment: Is the slow system running linux?

Comment: i don't think so. I'm on Distributor ID: Ubuntu //Release: 12.04 // kernel : 3.2.0-43-generic GNU/Linux // CPU : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 0 @ 2.20GHz // Memory 128 GIB .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the CUDA driver being loaded and a CUDA context (an environment where all your data and programs are held in the device) being created every time, which requires lots of bookkeeping. You can force the driver to be loaded at all times by doing the following as root:

```
nvidia-smi -pm 1
```

Which will enable the so-called "persistence mode" (set it to 0 to disable). This will speed up your initialisation.

Comment: It might help, but there is also the matter of the host machine have 128Gb of memory. The unified memory driver on Linux will map all of that host memory, plus every GPU into a virtual address space. The system calls necessary to do that are quite slow. The 4 extra seconds of initialisation time are probably a combination of these two factors.

Comment: Please see the response given by @talonmies.  Your two systems have different main memory amounts.   This affects the CUDA start up time.

Comment: Ok now it's work better. Thanks. user time (s): 1.480 system time (s): 1.520 elapsed time (s): 3.030. but i haven't understand why here i must force to load the driver and why with the other card without this command i have good result ? is it just because this card take more time to be loaded ? Reguj has explain and give me a solution for one factors of the problem. This is not the same explaine by talonnmies. I have understood the response given by @talonmies but he dosen't say if we could do something for this.